# How to start a transactional API event in marketing cloud with SOAP

Tags: journeybuilder, soap-api, transactional-messaging-api

I want to send an email (with a personalized template) to certain people when our program meets certain conditions. Transactional API events looks like the perfect candidate for this so I want to trigger a transactional API event. This works as intended when using REST (working in Postman), but because limitations in our software we need to use SOAP and that is where I am stuck because I get an error I don't understand: "Exception occurred during [Perform::Start]"

I made a transactional API event, and started it in marketing cloud.

The event definition key is called: "TEST_API"

this is linked to a data extension (which holds 2 parameters "SubscriberKey" and "EmailAddress", these were required fields in the "transactional API event"): "TESTDE"

Message definition (the email template): "TEST_API_C2"

Message configuration send classification(linked to a sender/delivery profile and Transactional CAN-SPAM classification): "TEST_Classification"

I have this working in REST:

POST:

```
https://mcMyUrl.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/email/messages/TEST1234
```

BODY:

```
{
  "definitionKey": "TEST_API",
  "recipient":
  {
   "contactKey": "MyEmail",
    "to": "MyEmail",
    "attributes": {
      "SubscriberKey": "MyEmail",
      "EmailAddress": "MyEmail"
    }
  }
}
```

But I need to use SOAP, I tried different requests but it keeps giving me "Exception occurred during [Perform::Start]"

Here is an example which I think is close to working:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>Perform</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:To>https://mcMyUrl.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-1234">
            <wsse:Username>SOAP_Username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username
            -token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">SOAP_Password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Action>start</Action>
         <Definitions>
            <Definition xsi:type="EmailSendDefinition">
               <CustomerKey>TEST_API_C2</CustomerKey>
            </Definition>
         </Definitions>
          <Subscribers>
               <SubscriberKey>MyEmail</SubscriberKey>
               <EmailAddress>MyEmail</EmailAddress>
               <Attributes>
                 <Name>SubscriberKey</Name>
                 <Value>MyEmail</Value>                 
               </Attributes>
          </Subscribers>
      </PerformRequestMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: unfortunately journey builder can only work with REST API not SOAP API